# How to upload files to s3 bucket without form?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, axios

I am trying to upload a file on s3 bucket after I convert the html into pdf. Everything good with it when sign the file but then when it uploads it I can only see 49B for the file size and can't be opened.

any idea?

here is my convertor and the upload function

```
const uploadDocumentToS3 = async (awsSign, file) => {
  try {
    var signedUrl = awsSign.signedRequest;

    var options = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/pdf"
      }
    };

    const upload = await axios.put(signedUrl, file, options);

    return upload;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

async function createStatement() {
  try {
    const content = await compile("statement", data);

    var options = { format: "A4" };
    var fileName = "template";
    pdf
      .create(content, options)
      .toFile(`./src/services/${fileName}.pdf`, async function(err, res) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        // get s3SignRequest
        const awsSign = await signS3(`${fileName}.pdf`, "application/pdf");
        // upload file to s3 Bucket
        const uploadRes = await uploadDocumentToS3(awsSign, res.filename);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you are actually not uploading the file, try to read it from the filesystem and append as form data in your request.

Comment: @dpolicastro I've done this `const document = .fs.readfile(file, "utf-8");` and in axios instead `file` I've added `document` now the file size is 1.6MB but when I open it I can only get 2 white pages